# Mathematica saying "NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy " for this integral ploting

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

```
Plot[y/(32*\[Pi]^4)*12^2*(2.09*10^-11)^2*100^2/(192 \[Pi])
 NIntegrate[((x - 2*100^2)^2 - 4*100^4)/Sqrt[x]
 Sqrt[(x - 4*100^2) (x - 4*100^2)/
 x^2] (x^2 - 4*100^2*x + 
  12*100^4)/((x - 5^2)^2 ((x - 100^2)^2 + (4.15*10^-3*100)^2))
 BesselK[1, Sqrt[x]/y], {x, 4*10^4, \[Infinity]}], {y, 8*10^-3, 
10^10}, PlotRange -> {{8*10^-3, 10^10}, {8*10^-44, 10^16}}]
```

When i am trying to plot it , Mathematica gives an empty plot and shows

```
NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {5.57963*10^7}. NIntegrate obtained 2.5480460753667857`*^6 and 21453.774416999564` for the integral and error estimates.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing:

```
a = 2 100^2;
b = 415 10^-3;

f[x_] := ((x - a)^2 - a^2)/Sqrt[x] (x - 2 a)/x (x^2 - 2 a x + 3 a^2)/((x - 25)^2 ((x - a/2)^2 + b^2)) 
g[x_, y_] := 131043/128 10^-22/Pi^5 f[x] y BesselK[1, Sqrt[x]/y]
h[y_] := NIntegrate[g[x, y], {x, 2 a, Infinity}, Method -> "Trapezoidal"]

Plot[h[y], {y, 8 10^-3, 10^10}]
```

I get:

> [image]

which is what is desired.

---

Wanting to specialize everything in the case of several plots to compare in the same plan, writing:

```
listA = {2, 10, 50} 100^2;
listB = {415, 420, 425} 10^-3;
listC = {Blue, Green, Red};
listD = {{"first"}, {"second"}, {"third"}};

f[x_] := ((x - a)^2 - a^2)/Sqrt[x] (x - 2 a)/x (x^2 - 2 a x + 3 a^2)/((x - 25)^2 ((x - a/2)^2 + b^2))
g[x_, y_] := 131043/128 10^-22/Pi^5 f[x] y BesselK[1, Sqrt[x]/y]
h[y_] := NIntegrate[g[x, y], {x, 2 a, Infinity}, Method -> "Trapezoidal"]

plots = Table[a = listA[[i]];
              b = listB[[i]]; 
              Plot[h[y], {y, 8 10^-3, 10^10},
                   PlotStyle -> listC[[i]],
                   PlotLegends -> listD[[i]]],
              {i, 3}];

Show[plots, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

I get:

> [image]

that seems to make her look good!

Comment: Is there any way to write a general code for such functions and by varying different parameters, i can get different desired results?

Comment: Like here in your written code a,b contains some variable squared and i have to plot 5 more such plots in the same graph with changing these variable

Comment: Yes, perfect. How to learn doing such well structured programmes. Can you provide me some good sources to learn them my own

Comment: Ok i will follow accordingly

Answer (score 1):

With adapted `PrecisionGoal` and `PlotRange` your code works without warning:

```
Plot[y/(32*\[Pi]^4)*12^2*(2.09*10^-11)^2*100^2/(192 \[Pi]) NIntegrate[((x - 2*100^2)^2 - 4*100^4)/Sqrt[x]Sqrt[(x - 4*100^2) (x - 4*100^2)/x^2] (x^2 - 4*100^2*x +12*100^4)/((x - 5^2)^2 ((x - 100^2)^2 + (4.15*10^-3*100)^2)) BesselK[1, Sqrt[x]/y], {x, 4*10^4, \[Infinity]}
,PrecisionGoal->5 ], {y, 8*10^-3,10^10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to write a general code for such functions and by varying different parameters i can get different desired results?

Comment: @DarkKnight45 It appears that the question is morphing. What have you tried thus far for coding a parametrized version?